# Equivalent function to pythons expanduser in nodejs?

Tags: javascript, node.js

In python if I need to access a path that includes the `~` character, I can use `os.path.expanduser()`. Is there a similar function (or library) in `node.js`?

I know I can do something like `file.replace(/~/, os.homedir())` but it won't properly handle all the special cases like when a `~` is not at the beginning or the `~user/` syntax.

Comment: wouldn't a better RegExp just do it? as in `file.replace(/^~\//, os.homedir())`

Comment: Yes, that would handle the `~` after the beginning but not the `~user` syntax

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there's any `path` API for that, but both mentioned cases look easily solvable via something like this:

```
const {homedir} = require('os');
const {dirname} = require('path');
const expanduser = text => text.replace(
  /^~([a-z]+|\/)/,
  (_, $1) => $1 === '/' ?
    homedir() : `${dirname(homedir())}/${$1}`
);
```

You can `expanduser('~/')` or `expanduser('~any')` and retrieve the expected result.